# How to set SELinux boolean using custom policy?

Tags: kvm-virtualization, selinux, qemu

I know that SElinux booleans can be set via `setsebool` like this:

```
setsebool -P virt_qemu_ga_read_nonsecurity_files 1
```

But I want to set this boolean `virt_qemu_ga_read_nonsecurity_files` using custom SELinux policy.

Is it even possible? How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A SELinux boolean is a switch to dynamically enable/disable a set of policies at runtime. If you want to enable the policies that this boolean enables without setting the boolean, you can implement the policies behind the boolean as a custom SELinux module and add it to your local policies.

Example:

1. Create a file `test.te`:

```
policy_module(test, 1.0)
gen_require(`
    type virt_qemu_ga_t ;
')
files_read_non_security_files(virt_qemu_ga_t)
```

2. `yum -y install policycoreutils-devel`
3. `make -f /usr/share/selinux/devel/Makefile test.pp`
4. `semodule -i test.pp`